# In robots.txt, why would there be "Allow: /*" below a Disallow rule?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot, web-crawlers

I want to allow full access to all Google

I am specially confused about `Allow: /*` below `Disallow:`

```
# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*

# Google AdSense
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Allow` directive is a non-standard extension to robots.txt.   The original robots.txt standard only includes `Disallow` directives.   Google's robots *do* understand `Allow` directives, so it would be OK to use them in sections targeted at a Google robot.  The `Allow` directive should only be used when it is more specific than `Disallow` directive.  This will counteract the `Disallow`.   It can be used to give finer grained allowance (maybe just a single page) of entire section that would otherwise be disallowed.

In your case, the `Allow` directive is saying the same thing as the `Disallow` directive, so it should be omitted.

You say you that you want to allow all Google robots to crawl all of your site.  If that is the case, you would need a rule for the main `Googlebot` as well.   I would suggest using this in your `robots.txt`

```
# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Google AdSense
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

# Googlebot
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:
```

Comment: "The `Allow` directive should always be used after a `Disallow` directive" - Actually, if anything, it should be the other way round. `Allow` _before_ `Disallow`. Whilst for the main search engine bots this doesn't matter, since the match is based on the specificity/length of the URL path. Some (old) bots supposedly use a "first match rule", whereby the first path matched wins. Having the `Allow` directive first, accommodates these others bots. Reference: http://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2009/08/20/prevent-a-bot-from-getting-lost-in-space-sem-101

Comment: I removed the advice about where it should go relative to the other rules altogether.   It doesn't seem relevant for this question since 1. it is Google, 2. I'm suggesting removing the rule.   The link you give is great for in depth exploration of the issue.